# Gridview filtering wont work when it has returned empty

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, filtering

I've managed to make a poor excuse for filtering a gridView that pretty much works EXCEPT for when I've entered a value that doesn't return anything.

for example, lets say that I have values 11, 12, 23 and 24. If I enter '1' in my textbox, I will only see '11' and '12' (this works even if the results are on different pages). When I remove the '1' I will see all the values again. Excellent!

But if I enter '3' it returns an empty table (so far so good) and when I remove the 3... Still empty! anyone knows why this is?

This is my (important) code:

**ASP**

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfText" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <input type="text" id="input" style="width: 66px;"/>
    <asp:GridView ID="myGv" runat="server" 
        ShowFooter="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="True"
        DataKeyNames="DataKeyId" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataKeyId" HeaderText="DataKey" Visible="false" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DataKeyId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="header1" HeaderText="Header1" SortExpression="header1" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="header2" HeaderText="Header2" SortExpression="header2" ReadOnly="True" />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
             No data found!
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="mySelectMethod" TypeName="WhereItsAt" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="header1" Type="String" Defaultvalue="" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     /* This piece of code just makes sure that the text remains after postback */
     $('#input').val($('#hfText').val());
     $('#input').focus();
     var textval = $('#input').val();
     $('#input').val("");
     $('#input').val(textval);
     /*******************/

     $('#input').keyup(function (event) {
         $('#hfText').val($('#input').val()).trigger('change');      
              __doPostBack('thisUrl.aspx', $('#input').val());
         });
     });
 });
```

**C# (Code behind)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        myGv.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Contains("Page$"))
        {
             reBind(Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
        }
    }
}

protected void reBind(String sParam)
{
    ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters.Remove(ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters["header1"]);
    ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("header1", sParam);
    myGv.DataBind();
}
```

(hope this isn't TL;DR)

**EDIT**
I get the javascript error "ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined" after entering a value that returns nothing and then entering a value that SHOULD return something!

Comment: Are you trying to search through a gridview using textbox?

Comment: I'm using the value from my textbox to re-bind the data in my gridview. so yeah, pretty much

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery plugin?

Comment: No, I wish to do it without plugins

Comment: why don't you add the textbox with asp.net server conrtrols and done redbind with the textbox text change event. Do you have any problem with that?

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery AJAX request instead of __doPostBack(), I don't feel that __doPostBack() is a right approach if you are using jQuery.

Comment: response to jalpesh and Learners last posts: I'm still pretty new to web development (.net/jquery/ajax/whatever). This was the first solution that I managed to get to work (sort of). If your suggestions might fix my problem, please explain how I go by doing it :)

Comment: As I was trying to say that this doesn't seem to be a right approach to me. I might not be able to help you with this. But, I can recommend you this: http://technology2grab.blogspot.ca/2012/10/how-to-search-through-gridview-records.html for question specific solution and http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ for jQuery AJAX and I personally use datatables plugin to achieve something like this: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html (pretty easy to implement and you don't need to worry about the quality and performance)

Comment: @Learner Thanks! I'll be sure to check out the links. If I find a solution myself I'll just answer this question myself :P (I realize that might have sounded sarcastic, but It wasn't ^^ thanks for your help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a supereasy solution!

All I had to do was add `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);` in my page-load like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        myGv.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
        if (!Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Contains("Page$"))
        {
             reBind(Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
        }
    }
}
```